# CMKY code for xcolor package?

Tags: color

I have three mdframed environments in my document.

```
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=blue!20]   

\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=purple!20] 

\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=brown!20]
```

Using the `xcolor` package. I am wondering how (if possible) I can recover the `CMKY` codes for the colours from this information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `\extractcolorspecs` macro from `xcolor` package and extract its model first to `\modelcmd` and the spec to `\colorcmd` and then use `\convertcolorspecs` to transform it to another specification, say `cmyk`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\extractcolorspecs{brown!20}{\modelcmd}{\colorcmd}
\convertcolorspec{\modelcmd}{\colorcmd}{cmyk}{\colorcmdcmyk}

\colorcmd

\colorcmdcmyk


\end{document}
```

**Update**

Direct conversion:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\convertdirectly}[3][cmyk]{%
  \extractcolorspecs{#2}{\modelcmd}{\colorcmd}%
  \convertcolorspec{\modelcmd}{\colorcmd}{#1}{#3}%
}

\begin{document}
\convertdirectly{brown!20}{\cmykbrown}
\convertdirectly[hsb]{brown!20}{\hsbbrown}
\convertdirectly[RGB]{brown!20}{\RGBbrown}

cmyk: \cmykbrown

hsb: \hsbbrown

RGB: \RGBbrown

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @AngusTheMan: Glad I could help. Happy Texing