# How do I get the hue, saturation and brightness values from a color?

Tags: macros, color, definition

I want to define a new colour (`myorange`) by changing the `hue` value of a previously given colour (`oldcolour`), thus maintaining its original saturation and brightness. Is there a way for doing this?

I can think of two strategies. First, having a function `\changehue` that returns a colour from another, but with a hue defined by the user. It would be used as follows:

```
\colorlet{myorange}{\changehue{oldcolour}{30}}
```

Or maybe:

```
\colorlet{myorange}{\changehue{oldcolour}{orange}}
```

In this last case, `\changehue` would extract the hue of `orange` and plug it into the code. This way would be better for me.

In the second strategy, we just define the colour with the `definecolor` with the `hsb` colour model with the help of functions for extracting the hue, saturation and brightness of the colour previously given.

```
\definecolor{myorange}{hsb}{\hue{orange}, \saturation{oldcolour}, \brightness{oldcolour}}
```

I strongly prefer this second strategy, which is the way presupposed by my question. It would be useful to know if commands like `\hue`, `\saturation`, and `\brightness` exist or can be defined.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This varies the hue value: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcounter{myc}
\begin{document}
\definecolorseries{changehue}{hsb}{step}{orange}{0,0.1,0}
\resetcolorseries[12]{changehue}%
\loop\stepcounter{myc}\colorlet{mycolor}{changehue!![\number\value{myc}]}
\textcolor{mycolor}{X}\ifnum\value{myc}<11\repeat
\end{document}` but you want to retrieve it from a given color, right?

Comment: Thanks, @Schrödinger'scat. Your proposal is very helpful and corresponds to the first strategy. It would be great, though, if something approximating the second could be proposed.

Comment: I agree with that, which is why I upvoted this question. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be a partial answer. You can define a color series and vary, say, the hue value. The perhaps more important information is that `\extractcolorspecs` allows you to extract the color specifications of a given color. This can be converted to a given color scheme with `\convertcolorspec`. The last two commands have been merged to [the `\convertdirectly` command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283618), which I am recycling here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283618
\newcommand{\convertdirectly}[3][hsb]{\begingroup%
  \extractcolorspecs{#2}{\modelcmd}{\colorcmd}%
  \convertcolorspec{\modelcmd}{\colorcmd}{#1}{\tmp}%
  \message{#2 in #1 is \tmp^^J}%
  \aftergroupdef#3\tmp}
\def\First#1,#2,#3{#1}
\def\Second#1,#2,#3{#2}
\def\Third#1,#2,#3{#3}
\newcommand{\hue}[1]{\convertdirectly{#1}{\tmp}%
\expandafter\First\tmp}
\newcommand{\Hue}[2]{\begingroup\convertdirectly{#1}{\tmp}%
\edef\res{\expandafter\First\tmp}%
\aftergroupdef#2\res}
\newcommand{\saturation}[1]{\convertdirectly{#1}{\tmp}%
\expandafter\Second\tmp}
\newcommand{\Saturation}[2]{\begingroup\convertdirectly{#1}{\tmp}%
\edef\res{\expandafter\Second\tmp}%
\aftergroupdef#2\res}
\newcommand{\brightness}[1]{\convertdirectly{#1}{\tmp}%
\expandafter\Third\tmp}
\newcommand{\Brightness}[2]{\begingroup\convertdirectly{#1}{\tmp}%
\edef\res{\expandafter\Third\tmp}%
\aftergroupdef#2\res}
\newcounter{myc}
\begin{document}
\definecolorseries{changehue}{hsb}{step}{orange}{0,0.1,0}
\resetcolorseries[12]{changehue}%
\loop\stepcounter{myc}\colorlet{mycolor}{changehue!![\number\value{myc}]}%
\extractcolorspecs{mycolor}{\modelcmd}{\colorcmd}%
model=\textcolor{mycolor}{\modelcmd},%
color=\textcolor{mycolor}{\colorcmd}\par\ifnum\value{myc}<11\repeat


the hsb ``code'' of orange is \convertdirectly{orange}{\hsborange}\hsborange

the hsb ``code'' of brown is \convertdirectly{brown}{\hsbbrown}\hsbbrown

hue of orange=\hue{orange}

saturation of orange=\saturation{orange}

brightness of orange=\brightness{orange}

\Hue{orange}{\myhue}\Saturation{blue}{\mysaturation}\Brightness{brown}\mybrightness

\definecolor{myorange}{hsb}{\myhue,\mysaturation,\mybrightness}

\textcolor{myorange}{Test}
\end{document}
```

[image]