# Define a `beamer` block type that changes with themes

Tags: beamer, color, block

I would like to define a `beamer` block that has a characteristic colour; e.g. the characteristic colour of `alertblock` is red and that of `exampleblock` is green.

However, I want the style, brightness, and saturation of this block to change according to the `beamer` themes and colour themes.

For starters, suppose my block is called `myblock` and its characteristic colour is orange. In the `default` theme it would be defined approximately as follows:

```
\newenvironment<>{myblock}[1]{%
  \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=orange,bg=white}%
  \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=white}%
  \begin{block}#2{#1}}{\end{block}}
```

But in the `Madrid` theme it would be:

```
\newenvironment<>{myblock}[1]{%
  \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=orange}%
  \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=orange!25!white}%
  \begin{block}#2{#1}}{\end{block}}
```

That is, of course, in the `default` colour theme. However, some some colour themes, like `beaver`, make these colours more opaque or more shiny. Is there a way to make sure that such opaqueness is also translated to `myblock`?

My strategy builds upon an answer of [@Schrödinger's cat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/509951/154737). I define a command that creates four colours that will be used for colouring the `body.fg`, `body.bg`, `title.fg`, and `title.bg` of our custom block. Those colours will be defined by change the hue of each `block body.fg`, `block body.bg`, `block title.fg`, and `block title.bg` to the hue of the desired characteristic colour. In this way, we maintain the original saturation and brightness of the `block` colours. For example, if the characteristic colour we want is orange, the following would correspond to the colours `block body.fg`, `block body.bg`, `block title.fg`, and `block title.bg` of our custom block.

- `blorangebodyfg`: hue of `orange`, saturation and brightness of `block body.fg`,
- `blorangebodybg`: hue of `orange`, saturation and brightness of `block body.bg`
- `blorangetitlefg`: hue of `orange`, saturation and brightness of `block title.fg`,
- `blorangetitlebg`: hue of `orange`, saturation and brightness of `block title.bg`,

For that purpose defined a special class (`beamerplus`) where I stored the necessary commands. Since the file is a bit long, I link it [here](https://textuploader.com/1ksn6).

The most important command is `\customblock`, which is defined as follows:

```
\newenvironment<>{customblock}[2][orange]{%
    \blockcolorset{bl#1}{#1}
    \setbeamercolor{block title}%
        {fg=bl#1titlefg,bg=bl#1titlebg}%
    \setbeamercolor{block body}%
        {fg=bl#1bodyfg,bg=bl#1bodybg}%
    \begin{block}#3{#2}}{\end{block}}
```

Where `\blockcolorset` automatically creates all the colours previously listed. When I call it, though, it gets some of the colours, but not in the expected way. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{beamerplus}

\usetheme{Berlin}
\usecolortheme{wolverine}    


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}


\begin{block}{Normal block}

  Sic mundus creatus est.

\end{block}

\begin{customblock}{Neutral (orange) block}

  Sic mundus creatus est.

\end{customblock}

\begin{customblock}[yellow]{Yellow block}

  Sic mundus creatus est.

\end{customblock}


\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And here is the output:

[image: Output pdf.]

What makes my head hurt is that if I use `exampleblock` as paradigm (instead of `block`) it doesn't get the colours at all. Here is the modified [cls file](http://txt.do/1ksnf).

And here is the output.

[image: Output pdf (exampleblock).]

What am doing I wrong?

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the links to the class files don't seem to work anymore