# Overlapping labels in PSTricks

Tags: pstricks

Consider the following example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[locale = DE]{siunitx}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{tikz}

\psset{dimen = m}

% data
\def\bredde{4.5}
\def\start{0}
\def\eleverNul{4}
\def\eleverEn{2}
\def\eleverTo{5}
\def\eleverTre{7}
\def\eleverFire{5}
\def\eleverFem{3}
% beregninger
\newcommand*\eleverSumNul{\eleverNul}
\newcommand*\eleverSumEn{\fpeval{\eleverSumNul+\eleverEn}}
\newcommand*\eleverSumTo{\fpeval{\eleverSumEn+\eleverTo}}
\newcommand*\eleverSumTre{\fpeval{\eleverSumTo+\eleverTre}}
\newcommand*\eleverSumFire{\fpeval{\eleverSumTre+\eleverFire}}
\newcommand*\eleverSumFem{\fpeval{\eleverSumFire+\eleverFem}}
\newcommand*\eleverTotal{\fpeval{\eleverSumFem}}
\def\andelB[#1]#2#3#4{%
  \pswedge[fillstyle = solid, fillcolor = #1]%
     {\radius}{\fpeval{round(#2/\eleverTotal*360,9)}}{\fpeval{round(#3/\eleverTotal*360,9)}}
  \ifstrequal{#1}{black}%
    {\psarc[linecolor = white]%
       (0,0){0.5}{\fpeval{round(#2/\eleverTotal*360,9)}}{\fpeval{round(#3/\eleverTotal*360,9)}}
     \uput{8pt}[\fpeval{round((#2+#3)/\eleverTotal*180,9)}]%
       (0,0){\textcolor{white}{\footnotesize\SI{\fpeval{round((#3-#2)/\eleverTotal*360)}}{\degree}}}}
    {\psarc%
       (0,0){0.5}{\fpeval{round(#2/\eleverTotal*360,9)}}{\fpeval{round(#3/\eleverTotal*360,9)}}
     \uput{8pt}[\fpeval{round((#2+#3)/\eleverTotal*180,9)}]%
       (0,0){\footnotesize\SI{\fpeval{round((#3-#2)/\eleverTotal*360)}}{\degree}}}%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Opgave~$7$}
\begin{center}
\psset{
  unit = 0.4,
  linejoin = 1
}
\def\radius{5}
  \begin{pspicture}(\fpeval{-(\radius+0.1)},\fpeval{-(\radius+0.1)})%
                   (\fpeval{+(\radius+0.1)},\fpeval{+(\radius+0.1)})
    \visible<4->{%
      \pscircle(0,0){\radius}
      \multido{\r = 0+\fpeval{round(360/\eleverTotal,9)}}{\eleverTotal}{%
      \psRelLine[angle = \r](0,0)(\fpeval{\radius+0.1},0){1}{EndNode}
      \psRelLine[angle = \r, linecolor = white, linewidth = 2\pslinewidth]%
        (0,0)(\fpeval{\radius-0.1},0){1}{EndNode}}}
    \visible<5->{\andelB[yellow!70]{\start}{\eleverSumNul}}
    \visible<6->{\andelB[red!70]{\eleverSumNul}{\eleverSumEn}}
    \visible<7->{\andelB[green!80]{\eleverSumEn}{\eleverSumTo}}
    \visible<8->{\andelB[orange!80]{\eleverSumTo}{\eleverSumTre}}
    \visible<9->{\andelB[blue!70!white]{\eleverSumTre}{\eleverSumFire}}
    \visible<10->{\andelB[black]{\eleverSumFire}{\eleverSumFem}}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

**Question**

As can be seen, the `28°` label is not printed "on top" of the green wedge. (It is of course the same of the other labels.)

How do I make sure that the labels are always printed "on top"?

Comment: At first sight, I don't understand the details of your code. However, a suggestion: can you put theses values  as some `\uput` at the middle of the arc it refers to? It shouldn't be hard in polar coordinates, and may be a convenient `multido` or `\foreach`.

Comment: @Bernard The code might very well be quite bad. `:-)` Can I make you give it a try with the `\uput`? I've tried but I keep missing something (obvious?).

Comment: I can try, but my problem is I don't understand where is the code to display the angles. Could you explain in a few words?

Comment: @Bernard Sure! The code to display the angels is within the `\ifstrequal` arguments in the `\andelB` macro in the preamble.

Comment: I've taken a look, but it has a long compiling time on my computer, and I ried didn't produce any change. As it' getting late here, I'll look at it again tomorrow.

Comment: @Bernard Yes, the compiliing ime is, unfiortunately, very long. `:-(` Thank you for trying again tomorrow. (I's also late in Denmark.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101616/discussion-between-bernard-and-svend-tveskaeg).

Comment: @Bernard I'm ready to continue our discussion. `:-)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With just a modification of some parameters:

```
    \documentclass{beamer}

    \usepackage[locale = DE]{siunitx}
    \usepackage{xfp}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \usepackage{pstricks-add}
    \usepackage{tikz}

    \psset{dimen = m}

    % data
    \def\bredde{4.5}
    \def\start{0}
    \def\eleverNul{4}
    \def\eleverEn{2}
    \def\eleverTo{5}
    \def\eleverTre{7}
    \def\eleverFire{5}
    \def\eleverFem{3}
    % beregninger
    \newcommand*\eleverSumNul{\eleverNul}
    \newcommand*\eleverSumEn{\fpeval{\eleverSumNul+\eleverEn}}
    \newcommand*\eleverSumTo{\fpeval{\eleverSumEn+\eleverTo}}
    \newcommand*\eleverSumTre{\fpeval{\eleverSumTo+\eleverTre}}
    \newcommand*\eleverSumFire{\fpeval{\eleverSumTre+\eleverFire}}
    \newcommand*\eleverSumFem{\fpeval{\eleverSumFire+\eleverFem}}
    \newcommand*\eleverTotal{\fpeval{\eleverSumFem}}
    \def\andelB[#1]#2#3#4{%
      \pswedge[fillstyle = solid, fillcolor = #1]%
         {\radius}{\fpeval{round(#2/\eleverTotal*360,9)}}{\fpeval{round(#3/\eleverTotal*360,9)}}
      \ifstrequal{#1}{black}%
        {\psarc[linecolor = white]%
           (0,0){1.5}{\fpeval{round(#2/\eleverTotal*360,9)}}{\fpeval{round(#3/\eleverTotal*360,9)}}%
         \uput{2}[\fpeval{round((#2+#3)/\eleverTotal*180,9)}]%8pt
           (0,0){\textcolor{white}{\footnotesize\SI{\fpeval{round((#3-#2)/\eleverTotal*360)}}{\degree}}}}
        {\psarc%
           (0,0){1.5}{\fpeval{round(#2/\eleverTotal*360,9)}}{\fpeval{round(#3/\eleverTotal*360,9)}}%
    %\def\r{}
         \uput{2}[\fpeval{round((#2+#3)/\eleverTotal*180,9)}]%
           (0,0){\footnotesize\SI{\fpeval{round((#3-#2)/\eleverTotal*360)}}{\degree}}}%
    }


    \begin{document}

    \begin{frame}{Opgave~$7$}
    \begin{center}
    \psset{
      unit = 0.4,
      linejoin = 1
    }
    \def\radius{5}
      \begin{pspicture}(\fpeval{-(\radius+0.1)},\fpeval{-(\radius+0.1)})%
                       (\fpeval{+(\radius+0.1)},\fpeval{+(\radius+0.1)})
        \visible<4->{%
          \pscircle(0,0){\radius}
          \multido{\r = 0+\fpeval{round(360/\eleverTotal,9)}}{\eleverTotal}{%
          \psRelLine[angle = \r](0,0)(\fpeval{\radius+0.1},0){1}{EndNode}
          \psRelLine[angle = \r, linecolor = white, linewidth = 2\pslinewidth]%
            (0,0)(\fpeval{\radius-0.1},0){1}{EndNode}}}
        \visible<5->{\andelB[yellow!70]{\start}{\eleverSumNul}}
        \visible<6->{\andelB[red!70]{\eleverSumNul}{\eleverSumEn}}
        \visible<7->{\andelB[green!80]{\eleverSumEn}{\eleverSumTo}}
        \visible<8->{\andelB[orange!80]{\eleverSumTo}{\eleverSumTre}}
        \visible<9->{\andelB[blue!70!white]{\eleverSumTre}{\eleverSumFire}}
        \visible<10->{\andelB[black]{\eleverSumFire}{\eleverSumFem}}
      \end{pspicture}
    \end{center}
    \end{frame}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

*Added*: Using the value  5.3 as the first argument of `\uput` (in the place of 2) in the definition of `\andelB`, you'll get label outside the big circle. (In this case, don't forget to remove `\textcolor{white}` for the black sector):

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Which parameters have you changed? I guess the label separation, but other than that?

Comment: I changed the radius of the small arcs (`1.5` in the place of `0.5`) and the distance of the labels from the origin (not `8pt`, but `2` (psunits)).

Comment: But you didn't find a way to write the labels on top?

Comment: On top of the big (outer) circle?

Comment: On top of the wedges when printing the wedge to the left of the labels, going counter clockwise. (example: Print `28°` on top of the red area when printing the green area) in order to not let the wedge overlap the label ... i.e. in order to solve the original problem.

Comment: In the definition of `\andelB` replace each `\uput{2}` (was 8pt in your initial version) with `\uput{5.3}`. I'll add that maybe the compiling time would be shorter using `pst-eucl` and its \pstBissectBAC`  command.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Always glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

The mandatory argument for `\uput{<distance>}` defines the distance away from the point in question you'll place the contents to be put. You're using `8pt` in your `\andelB` macro... increase this to something larger, like `25pt`:

[image]

```
\def\andelB[#1]#2#3#4{%
  \pswedge[fillstyle = solid, fillcolor = #1]%
     {\radius}{\fpeval{round(#2/\eleverTotal*360,9)}}{\fpeval{round(#3/\eleverTotal*360,9)}}
  \ifstrequal{#1}{black}%
    {\psarc[linecolor = white]%
       (0,0){0.5}{\fpeval{round(#2/\eleverTotal*360,9)}}{\fpeval{round(#3/\eleverTotal*360,9)}}
     \uput{25pt}[\fpeval{round((#2+#3)/\eleverTotal*180,9)}]%
       (0,0){\textcolor{white}{\footnotesize\SI{\fpeval{round((#3-#2)/\eleverTotal*360)}}{\degree}}}}
    {\psarc%
       (0,0){0.5}{\fpeval{round(#2/\eleverTotal*360,9)}}{\fpeval{round(#3/\eleverTotal*360,9)}}
     \uput{25pt}[\fpeval{round((#2+#3)/\eleverTotal*180,9)}]%
       (0,0){\footnotesize\SI{\fpeval{round((#3-#2)/\eleverTotal*360)}}{\degree}}}%
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\psset{
  unit = 0.4,opacity=0.5,
  linejoin = 1
}
```

[image]

However, you can fool `\psChart` to let all calculation done by the macro:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\newcounter{temp}
\def\Chart{\psChart{55,28,69,97,69,42}{}{4}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Opgave~$7$}
\begin{center}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
\visible<1->{%
  \psset{userColor={yellow!70,white,white,white,white,white}}\Chart
  \rput(psChartI1){55}}
\visible<2->{%
  \psset{userColor={yellow!70,red!70,white,white,white,white}}\Chart
  \rput(psChartI1){55}\rput(psChartI2){28}}
\visible<3->{%
  \psset{userColor={yellow!70,red!70,green!80,white,white,white}}\Chart
  \rput(psChartI1){55}\rput(psChartI2){28}\rput(psChartI3){69}}
\visible<4->{%
  \setcounter{temp}{0}%
  \psset{userColor={yellow!70,red!70,green!80,orange!80,white,white}}\Chart
  \psforeach{\iA}{55,28,69,97}{\stepcounter{temp}\rput(psChartI\thetemp){\iA}}}
\visible<5->{%
  \setcounter{temp}{0}%
  \psset{userColor={yellow!70,red!70,green!80,orange!80,blue!70!white,white}}\Chart
  \psforeach{\iA}{55,28,69,97,69}{\stepcounter{temp}\rput(psChartI\thetemp){\iA}}}
\visible<6>{%
  \setcounter{temp}{0}%
  \psset{userColor={yellow!70,red!70,green!80,orange!80,blue!70!white,black}}\Chart
  \psforeach{\iA}{55,28,69,97,69}{\stepcounter{temp}\rput(psChartI\thetemp){\iA}}
  \rput(psChartI6){\color{white}42}}
\pscircle{4}
\degrees[26]\multido{\iA=0+1}{26}{\psline(4;\iA)(4.1;\iA)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun: a Ti*k*Z alternative. You only need to specify the lists of numbers and colors,

```
\def\LstNums{4,2,5,7,5,3}
\def\LstColors{"yellow!70","red!70","green!80","orange!80","blue!70!white","black"}
```

and the code will do the rest. The colors of the label are chose complementary to the fill color, based on the RGB color model. (Quite possible that other color models look better/different.) This way the labels and the inner arcs are visible. The animation starts at slide 4 (`\def\istart{4}`), as in your code.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles,backgrounds}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283618
\newcommand{\convertdirectly}[3][hsb]{\begingroup%
  \extractcolorspecs{#2}{\modelcmd}{\colorcmd}%
  \convertcolorspec{\modelcmd}{\colorcmd}{#1}{\tmp}%
  \aftergroupdef#3\tmp}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Opgave~$7$}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={R=3;}]
 \def\istart{4}
 \def\LstNums{4,2,5,7,5,3}
 \def\LstColors{"yellow!70","red!70","green!80","orange!80","blue!70!white","black"}
 \def\mysum{0}
 \foreach \X [remember=\mysum as \mysum]in \LstNums
 {\pgfmathsetmacro{\mysum}{\mysum+\X}
 \xdef\pgfmathresult{\mysum}}
 \edef\mytotal{\pgfmathresult}
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mydim}{dim(\LstNums)-1}
 \draw[thick,visible on=<\istart->] circle[radius=R*1cm]
 foreach \X in {0,10,...,350} {(\X:R) -- (\X:R+0.05)};
 \def\mysum{0}
 \foreach \X [remember=\mysum as \mysum] in {0,...,\mydim}
 {\pgfmathsetmacro{\mypercentage}{{\LstNums}[\X]/\mytotal}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{{\LstColors}[\X]}
   \begin{scope}[on background layer]
   \draw[visible on=<\the\numexpr\istart+1+\X\relax->,fill=\mycolor]
    (0,0) -- (\mysum:R) arc(\mysum:\mysum+\mypercentage*360:R) --cycle;
  \end{scope}   
  \convertdirectly[RGB]{\mycolor}{\currRGB}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\currR}{255-{\currRGB}[0]}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\currG}{255-{\currRGB}[1]}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\currB}{255-{\currRGB}[2]}
  \definecolor{tmp}{RGB}{\currR,\currG,\currB}
  \draw[visible on=<\the\numexpr\istart+1+\X\relax->,color=tmp,thick] 
   (\mysum:0.2*R) arc(\mysum:\mysum+\mypercentage*360:0.2*R)
   (\mysum+\mypercentage*180:0.6*R) node
   {$\pgfmathparse{int(360*\mypercentage+0.5)}\pgfmathresult^\circ$};
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\mysum}{\mysum+{\LstNums}[\X]*360/\mytotal} 
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you move the labels closer to the center, they will not get overpainted by the wedges since the wedges are drawn on the `background` layer.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{cmyk}{xcolor}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles,backgrounds}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283618
\newcommand{\convertdirectly}[3][hsb]{\begingroup%
  \extractcolorspecs{#2}{\modelcmd}{\colorcmd}%
  \convertcolorspec{\modelcmd}{\colorcmd}{#1}{\tmp}%
  \aftergroupdef#3\tmp}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Opgave~$7$}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={R=3;}]
 \def\istart{4}
 \def\LstNums{4,2,5,7,5,3}
 \def\LstColors{"yellow!70","red!70","green!80","orange!80","blue!70!white","black"}
 \def\mysum{0}
 \foreach \X [remember=\mysum as \mysum]in \LstNums
 {\pgfmathsetmacro{\mysum}{\mysum+\X}
 \xdef\pgfmathresult{\mysum}}
 \edef\mytotal{\pgfmathresult}
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mydim}{dim(\LstNums)-1}
 \draw[thick,visible on=<\istart->] circle[radius=R*1cm]
 foreach \X in {0,10,...,350} {(\X:R) -- (\X:R+0.05)};
 \def\mysum{0}
 \foreach \X [remember=\mysum as \mysum] in {0,...,\mydim}
 {\pgfmathsetmacro{\mypercentage}{{\LstNums}[\X]/\mytotal}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{{\LstColors}[\X]}
   \begin{scope}[on background layer]
   \draw[visible on=<\the\numexpr\istart+1+\X\relax->,fill=\mycolor]
    (0,0) -- (\mysum:R) arc(\mysum:\mysum+\mypercentage*360:R) --cycle;
  \end{scope}   
  \convertdirectly[cmy]{\mycolor}{\currhsb}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\currc}{1-{\currhsb}[0]}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\currm}{1-{\currhsb}[1]}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\curry}{1-{\currhsb}[2]}
  \definecolor{tmp}{cmy}{\currc,\currm,\curry}
  \draw[visible on=<\the\numexpr\istart+1+\X\relax->,color=tmp,thick] 
   (\mysum:0.2*R) arc(\mysum:\mysum+\mypercentage*360:0.2*R)
   node[midway,circle,inner sep=1pt,anchor=180+\mysum+\mypercentage*180]
   {$\pgfmathparse{int(360*\mypercentage+0.5)}\pgfmathresult^\circ$};
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\mysum}{\mysum+{\LstNums}[\X]*360/\mytotal} 
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here I used the `cmy` color model. Of course, it is quite possible that there are better mappings than `x\mapsto 1-x` for `x\in\{c,m,y\}`. Yet it the result is IMHO well readable.

Comment: Great! Unfortunately I don't know TikZ but I will of course upvote your very nice answer.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I used PSTricks for almost 20 years and switched to Ti*k*Z a bit more than 2 years ago. In the beginning the syntax appears to be a bit unusual, but very soon one typically discovers that it is really cool. When I convert my old PSTricks pictures to Ti*k*Z, the code typically shrinks by a factor 2 or 3, and the result becomes much easier to generalize or adjust. But I perfectly understand how one can hesitate to switch, I also felt that way for a long time.