# A problem with \convertdirectly and xcolor

Tags: color

I have been working with [How do I get the hue, saturation and brightness values from a color?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/509949/how-do-i-get-the-hue-saturation-and-brightness-values-from-a-color/509951#509951) and have run across a problem. The very useful function `\convertdirectly` is defined (copied from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283618) and from it a command `\hue` is defined. This returns the hue (hsb) of a given color: `\hue{orange}` gives `0.08333` for example.

Other colors, such as purple (hue=0.94444.75) give unexpected figures for hue. It is relatively easy to what is happening, but not how to fix it as the code appears to be very straightforward.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283618
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/509949/how-do-i-get-the-hue-saturation-and-brightness-values-from-a-color
\newcommand{\convertdirectly}[3][hsb]{\begingroup%
  \extractcolorspecs{#2}{\modelcmd}{\colorcmd}%
  \convertcolorspec{\modelcmd}{\colorcmd}{#1}{\tmp}%
  \message{#2 in #1 is \tmp^^J}%
  \aftergroupdef#3\tmp}
\def\First#1,#2,#3{#1}
\def\Second#1,#2,#3{#2}
\def\Third#1,#2,#3{#3}
\newcommand{\hue}[1]{\convertdirectly{#1}{\tmp}%
\expandafter\First\tmp}
\newcommand{\Hue}[2]{\begingroup\convertdirectly{#1}{\tmp}%
\edef\res{\expandafter\First\tmp}%
\aftergroupdef#2\res}
\newcommand{\saturation}[1]{\convertdirectly{#1}{\tmp}%
\expandafter\Second\tmp}
\newcommand{\Saturation}[2]{\begingroup\convertdirectly{#1}{\tmp}%
\edef\res{\expandafter\Second\tmp}%
\aftergroupdef#2\res}
\newcommand{\brightness}[1]{\convertdirectly{#1}{\tmp}%
\expandafter\Third\tmp}
\newcommand{\Brightness}[2]{\begingroup\convertdirectly{#1}{\tmp}%
\edef\res{\expandafter\Third\tmp}%
\aftergroupdef#2\res}
\newcounter{myc}
\begin{document}

\parindent0pt

\def\testit#1{The hue of #1 is \hue{#1} (hsb spec: \tmp).\par}

\testit{orange}
\testit{red}

\bigskip

\testit{purple}
\testit{red!60!blue}
\testit{red!80!purple}

\end{document}

%% |=====8><----| %%
```

[image: output of hue]

Answer (score 1):

The macros `\First` `\Second` and `\Third` needed to have `#3` delimited -- I chose the vertbar. Everything works now as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283618
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/509949/how-do-i-get-the-hue-saturation-and-brightness-values-from-a-color
\newcommand{\convertdirectly}[3][hsb]{\begingroup%
  \extractcolorspecs{#2}{\modelcmd}{\colorcmd}%
  \convertcolorspec{\modelcmd}{\colorcmd}{#1}{\tmp}%
  \message{#2 in #1 is \tmp^^J}%
  \aftergroupdef#3\tmp}
\def\First#1,#2,#3|{#1}
\def\Second#1,#2,#3|{#2}
\def\Third#1,#2,#3|{#3}
\newcommand{\hue}[1]{\convertdirectly{#1}{\tmp}%
\expandafter\First\tmp|}
\newcommand{\Hue}[2]{\begingroup\convertdirectly{#1}{\tmp}%
\edef\res{\expandafter\First\tmp|}%
\aftergroupdef#2\res}
\newcommand{\saturation}[1]{\convertdirectly{#1}{\tmp}%
\expandafter\Second\tmp|}
\newcommand{\Saturation}[2]{\begingroup\convertdirectly{#1}{\tmp}%
\edef\res{\expandafter\Second\tmp|}%
\aftergroupdef#2\res}
\newcommand{\brightness}[1]{\convertdirectly{#1}{\tmp}%
\expandafter\Third\tmp|}
\newcommand{\Brightness}[2]{\begingroup\convertdirectly{#1}{\tmp}%
\edef\res{\expandafter\Third\tmp|}%
\aftergroupdef#2\res}
\newcounter{myc}
\begin{document}

\parindent0pt

\def\testit#1{The hue of #1 is \hue{#1} (hsb spec: \tmp).\par}

\testit{orange}
\testit{red}

\bigskip

\testit{purple}
\testit{red!60!blue}
\testit{red!80!purple}

\end{document}

%% |=====8><----| %%
```

[image: correct output]